# React UI not updating

Tags: reactjs

In an button-click I have some longer going process (**compileProject** which is synchronous). When state.compiling is set, it should show a spinner, but the UI freezes until compile is done. How can I update the UI ?

```
this.setState({ compiling: true }, () => {
    compileProject(this.state.project)
    this.setState({ compiling: false })
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JS is single-threaded a longer running computation will always block the UI thread. You can try to split the work into smaller chunks and schedule chunk computation with `requestAnimationFrame` or you could use webworkers.

Comment: Thanks, that was the explanation i was looking for.

Comment: @MatthiasThaler you can change the accepted answer to this if you wish. +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the second setState in a function and pass it to compileProject as a callback

```
this.setState({ compiling: true }, () => {
        compileProject(this.state.project, () => (this.setState({ compiling: false })))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I update the UI ?

You could try something like this.

```
this.setState({ compiling: true }, () => {
    setTimeout( ()=>compileProject(this.state.project, ()=>this.setState({ compiling: false }) ),
     0);

  })
```

Execute the callback at the end of `compileProject()`

`setTimeout` with `0` buy time for UI rendering. This should show the spinner, but UI hanging is a diffrent issue. See [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53538144/1188322)'s answer for that